# Does Unity video player support smooth streaming or video on demand or HLS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, video-player

I'm developing an augmented-reality application in unity which shows a video from the azure blobs, recently i changed the blob to have a streaming end point using the azure media services. But the problem is when i gave the streaming end point URL for the unity video player it shows error like below

### WindowsVideoMedia error 0xc00d36c4

> Context: MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL Error details: The byte stream
> type of the given URL is unsupported. Track types

Answer (score 4):

according to the [Video file compatability](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html) page on the unity manual the only supported video formats for windows (linux and osx have a subsection of these) are:

> .asf .avi .dv .m4v .mov .mp4 .mpg .mpeg .ogv .vp8 .webm .wmv

Seeing that HLS uses .m3u8 header files and .ts video files it is not supported by the native Unity video player.

There are however some plugins that do support these video formats, do note that some of these do cost money.

- [AVPro video](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/avpro-video-56355)
- [Easy Movie Texture](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/easy-movie-texture-video-texture-10032)
- [UMP](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/ump-win-mac-linux-webgl-49625)
- [VLC for unity (Windows)](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/vlc-for-unity-windows-133979) - Has a new asset that support Unity 2019.2.9 and up.

Note that I have no affiliation with *any* of these plugins, and there are possibly alternative options out there. these are just players i know are capable of playing HLS and on demand.

Comment: I had checked these plugins. Seems a bit expensive. Actually I came to know that by modifying this video streaming url in someways would work in unity video player but I couldn't see any code.

Comment: I tried an .ogv file hosted in azure instead of any streaming video url. But this doesn't even start playing and no errors shown as well

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/vlc-for-unity-windows-133979 VLC is back

Comment: @mtz Awesome, thanks for letting me know. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This NexPlayer Video Plugin supports HLS and DASH, as well as Video On Demand. 
It's the only video pluging that supports videos with DRM protection on all Android and iOS devices.

[GiHub Link added here](https://github.com/NexPlayer/NexPlayer_Unity_Plugin)

Comment: The NexPlayer does not have Vulkan graphics API support on Android.